# Creating list of dictionaries from txt using values from for loop

Tags: python, flask

Need to create a list of dictionaries with keys `'Date'` and `'Value'`. The values of keys are stored in a txt file with following structure:

```
test.txt
01-01-2020 12:00:00,10
01-01-2020 13:00:00,9
01-01-2020 14:00:00,8
01-01-2020 15:00:00,7
01-01-2020 16:00:00,6
01-01-2020 17:00:00,5
...
```

The outputs with below code is `{"01-01-2020 12:00:00":"10", "01-01-2020 13:00:00":"9"}...`

What I would like to do is `[{"Date":"01-01-2020 12:00:00","Value":"10"},{"Date":"01-01-2020 13:00:00","Value":"9"}...]`

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

```
import flask
from flask import request, jsonify

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def api_data():
    with open (r"test.txt","r") as f:
        # d={}
        l=[]
        for line in f.read().splitlines()[-5:]:
            d={}
            key,val = line.split(",")
            d[key] = val
        return d
    
app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have created the dictionary object using the date value as the key but if you need the keys to be string `Date` and `Value`, you can do the following:

```
def api_data():
    with open (r"test.txt","r") as f:
        l=[]
        for line in f.read().splitlines()[-5:]:
            key,val = line.split(",")
            d = {"Date": key, "Value" : val}
            l.append(d)
        return l

res = api_data()
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[{'Date': '01-01-2020 13:00:00', 'Value': '9'}, {'Date': '01-01-2020 14:00:00', 'Value': '8'}, {'Date': '01-01-2020 15:00:00', 'Value': '7'}, {'Date': '01-01-2020 16:00:00', 'Value': '6'}, {'Date': '01-01-2020 17:00:00', 'Value': '5'}]
```

Also, you need to `append` each object to the list and return the list object; currently you are returning the dictionary object.